# Running a raspberry pi(wiring pi) node with roslaunch

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble to run a node present in /ros_workspace/devel/lib/blink where blink is the package and this directory contains the blink executable, this executable is ran with root permission, I dont understand the work around with roslaunch with such files.

How can I run this with one roslaunch with other nodes in the bot.

Please let me know any other info that maybe needed to solve this.
thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299620/running-a-raspberry-pi(wiring-pi)-node-with-roslaunch/) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source the workspace?

Normally, the source call is made in ~/.bashrc, but you can also just use it from the command line.

For ROS kinetic:

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

and, in your case, assuming that your catkin workspace is actually ~/ros_workspace:

```
source ~/ros_workspace/devel/setup.bash
```

Then you should be able to do

```
roslaunch blink blink
```

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2018-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on 2018-08-05**:
how can I make the launch automatically ask for root access and automatically run as root, as  wiringpi cpp requires root access.

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2018-08-06**:
That's a common problem with wiringpi and ROS. You will have to go through the hassle of setting permissions on /dev/mem and /dev/gpiomem.  I suggest considering alternatives like pigpio or RPi.gpio where the permissions are already setup.